# Unable to get request token from linked-j on Android

Tags: android, linkedin-j

I'm using the linkedin-j library in my Android application. I'm trying to retrieve a request token for OAuth authentication:

```
LinkedInOAuthService linkedinOAuth = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(
                  linkedinApiKey,
                  linkedinSecretKey); 
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = linkedinOAuth.getOAuthRequestToken(MY_CALLBACK_URL);
```

I get this error:

```
11-19 22:20:56.985: E/AndroidRuntime(17891): com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
11-19 22:20:56.985: E/AndroidRuntime(17891):    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:180)
```

Anyone know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to place the getOAuthRequestToken into an AsyncTask so that it runs separate from the UI thread.